# Why is this IF statement evaluating to false when all conditions are true?

Tags: php, if-statement

In this case, the values for $r, $g, $b are:

```
r: 113
g: 113
b: 105
```

/

```
$threshold = 10;
if ((abs($r - $g) <= $threshold) && (abs($r - $b) <= $threshold) && (abs($g - b) <= $threshold))
{
  return TRUE;
}
else
{
  echo "<hr/>";
  var_dump((abs($r - $g) <= $threshold) && (abs($r - $b) <= $threshold) && (abs($g - b) <= $threshold)); //bool(false) 
  echo abs($r - $g) . "<br />"; //0
  echo abs($r - $b) . "<br />"; //8
  echo abs($g - $b) . "<br />"; //8
  echo $threshold . "<br />"; //10
  var_dump( (abs($r - $g) <= $threshold)); //bool(true)
  var_dump( (abs($r - $b) <= $threshold)); //bool(true)
  var_dump( (abs($g - $b) <= $threshold)); //bool(true)
}
```

This is the output

```
bool(false) 0
8
8
10
bool(true) bool(true) bool(true)
```

If all the conditions for the IF statement are TRUE, why is it evaluating to FALSE?

Comment: Is the missing `$` on the `b` variable in your actual code, or just a typo in this question?

Comment: You forgot the $ in front of the b in `abs($g - b) <= $threshold`

Comment: @aynber - please post this as the answer so I can give you credit. I knew it was something dumb but I couldn't find it, just needed an extra pair of eyes

Comment: It's never a welcome piece of advice but I suggest you enable full error reporting so PHP can notify these typos to you.

Comment: As already been stated, the last clause in your if condition-set evaluates to false, i.e.` (abs($g - b) <= $threshold)` - `b` here is taken as a literal character, so `abs($g - b)` will evaluate to 113 and that is not less than or equal to `$threshold` (which is 10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `$` in front of the b in `abs($g - b) <= $threshold`. With error reporting on, you'd see `Use of undefined constant b - assumed 'b'`.

Comment: I have no idea why someone voted this down, since it is the correct answer.

Comment: Because it's really not a necessary answer, since it's just a typo. :-)